# SELECT ONE ROW that has a priority value = 1 otherwise select the lowest queue id

Tags: sql, queue, sql-order-by, priority-queue

I am making a FCFS but with Priority algorithm. What is the best sql command to select first the priority regardless of queue id. And if there's no priority in the queue, then select the first in line or the least queue id. Thank you

Sample Table name cashier_queue_list

[image]

Here in the table, for that scenario, queue no 3 will be selected since it has a priority value of 1. then after that queue has been removed from the table, it should probably select 5 after the next run, next 7, and now without priority, queue 1. Please help thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want `order by`?

```
select *
from mytable
order by 
    priority desc, -- priority 1 comes first
    queue_id       -- then sort queues by ascending order (least id comes first)
```

If you wanted to interleave priority and non-priority items:

```
select *
from mytable
order by 
    row_number() over(partition by priority order by queue_id),
    priority desc
```

Comment: Yeah just like that, thanks. But how about alternating queue? One priority, one non priority